# How to exclude @EnableJpaRepositories from test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-data, spring-mvc-test

I have a main `@SpringBootApplication` which needs to scan a specific package in order to enable the JPA repositories, so I use `@EnableJpaRepositories` to specify that. Right now I'm implementing unit tests and I want to test the Controller component only, so I followed the tutorial in the official docs where they use `@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)` to test a controller with a service dependency.
The problem is that this is not working for me because it is trying to load the JpaRepositories that I specify in the main Spring Boot application (when I comment the `@EnableJpaRepositories` in the main class the test runs without problem).

I'm guessing I need to create a specific configuration for the test class so it can ignore the main configuration (since I only want to load the Controller and mock the service layer), but I don't know how to create such. I tried adding an empty configuration, but it is still failing with the same error:

```
@TestConfiguration
static class TestConfig {}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'failureTaskHandler': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'msgManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'inboundManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'messageRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageRepository' defined in com.example.MessageRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on MonitorApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#45e639ee' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#45e639ee': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

And my test class:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

  @Autowired private MockMvc mvc;

  @MockBean private MyService service;


  // Tests here

  // @Test
  // public void...


}
```

MyController class:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Slf4j
public class MyController {

  @Autowired private MyService service;

  @PostMapping(value = "/search", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public @ResponseBody SearchResponse getOrders(@RequestBody SearchRequest orderSearchRequest) {
    log.info("Receiving orders request...");
    return service.getOrders(orderSearchRequest);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you show the code of MyController

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the original post

Comment: And where is myManager used?

Comment: myManager is part of some external libraries I use in other parts of the main application, but I want to ignore all those, since I will be mocking the service response because I'm unit testing the controller. myManager is not used by the repository or the service, is just another functionality of my application.

Answer (score 6):

**Quick solution**

Remove `@EnableJpaRepositories` from your Spring Boot Application class. Use:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication { 

}
```

in place of

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class MainApplication { 

}
```

In this case Spring Boot will find Spring Data JPA on the classpath and uses auto-configuration to scan packages for the repositories.

**Use `@EnableJpaRepositories` to scan a specific package**

Use @NikolaiShevchenko solution (it is incorrect) with a separate configuration, but without explicit importing it, by `@Import({ DataConfiguration.class })`, (because tests will be explicitly import the configuration too) and let Spring Boot find your configuration during packages scan.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication { 

}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.app.entities")
public class JpaConfig {

}
```

**Important**

Don't forget to add `basePackages` property, if you put your configuration in a separate package.

Comment: Separating the `@EnableJpaRepositories` in a separate configuration class indeed does the trick. I wonder if that is a bug in the test engine.

Comment: @BrunoMedeiros It is not a bug. A test import all the configuration form `@SpringBootApplication` class. It doesn't touch a separate database configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Declare separate configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DataConfiguration { ... }
```

Import it into the application

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ DataConfiguration.class })
public class MainApplication { ... }
```

but don't import into `MyControllerTest`

Comment: The main application works fine doing this but the test class is still failing with the same error

Comment: @ErickSiordia Just remove this `@Import({ DataConfiguration.class })`